# Batch file disable services

Tags: windows-7, batch, services

This is a snipped of my batch file. I need to determine if the service exists, if it is running, stop it, change to disabled in one nice line.

```
echo.&echo.&echo =====Disable services=====
echo.
for %%x in (
"Mcx2Svc"   
"NetTcpPortSharing" 
"RemoteRegistry"
"SharedAccess"
"fax"
"TabletInputService"
"RemoteAccess"
"UxSms"
"Bdesvc"
"EFS"
"wsearch"
"ehsched"
"ehRecvr"
) do (sc query %%x| find "STATE" >nul 2>&1 && sc query %%x| find "RUNNING" >nul 2>&1 && echo Changing services to disabled: %%x && sc config %%x start= disabled)
```

Comment: And what is the question? Doesn't your nice line work as expected?

Comment: I used a different approach. I ended all that I didn't need without check. No need for check. If it exists, you end it, if not, it will say not found. No harm done, no 'if-s for-s and do-s' needed.

Answer (score 0):

The stacked sc query and find don't make sense to me.
Even if not one nice line this is IMHO more clear.

```
@Echo off
echo.&echo.&echo =====Disable services=====
echo.
for %%x in (
  "Mcx2Svc"   
  "NetTcpPortSharing" 
  "RemoteRegistry"
  "SharedAccess"
  "fax"
  "TabletInputService"
  "RemoteAccess"
  "UxSms"
  "Bdesvc"
  "EFS"
  "wsearch"
  "ehsched"
  "ehRecvr"
) do For /f "tokens=1-3 delims=: " %%S in (
  'sc query %%x ^|findstr /i "STATE" 2^>^&1 '
) Do (
  echo Changing services to disabled: %%x %%S %%T %%U
  Echo sc config %%x start= disabled
)
```

The for /f parses the output of sc query and filters the line with STATE, storing to the vars %%S,%%T,%%U
To show what would be executed sc config is preceeded with an echo. Remove the echo to activate the command.